# List<T>.Where Where won't show up in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, list

I'm reading Jon Skeet's book and he offers a great example:

```
List<Product> products = Product.GetSampleProducts();

foreach (Product product in products.Where(p => p.Price > 10))
{
    Console.WriteLine(product);
}
```

This seems pretty straightforward to me. But, when I try to do the same, the Where does not show up in the intellisense. Am I missing something? It looks the same.

```
List<lead> prospects = GetAllProspects();

foreach (lead prospect in prospects)
{

}
```

Comment: Just in case adding the namespace the others suggested doesn't work, check to make sure you also have a reference to `System.Core.dll` too.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add a reference to System.Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Make sure your project is targeting .Net 3.5 or greater.

Comment: Ah! There you go. Thumb up for the quick reply and thanks for the help!

Comment: Should be "Add a reference to `System.Core.dll`" and add the following directive to your source file:  "`using System.Linq;`"

Answer (score 3):

Are you referencing `System.Linq`? That's the library wherein the [Where extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) resides...